# error TS2339: Property 'customer' does not exist on type 'Customer'

Tags: angular, rest

I tried to create an interface for the REST API and I've got the error in the title. I attached the code and the image with the console. I would appreciate any help.

```html
 import { Customer } from '../components/hero/models/customer';
 
 getCustomerInfo(ndg: string): Observable<Customer> {
    const url = `${environment.apiUrl}${environment.ur3Path}cifCustomerDetails/customers/${ndg}`;
    return this.apiService.get(url);
  }
```

```html
export interface Customer {
    name: string;
    surname: string;
    emails: Array<Emails>;
}

export interface Emails {
    address: string;
}
```

[image]

Comment: post the code which fails

Comment: the interface above i think is the problem

Comment: i added this interface in the service instead of the <any>

Comment: Show the TS Code

Comment: ok i will edit it

Comment: The error message should tell you precisely which line of code has the error. You still haven't posted that line of code. But the message is quite clear: at that unknown line, you're trying to access the property `customer` of an object of type `Customer`. But there is no such property declared in the class `Customer`. That's what the error means.

Comment: @AndreiGhervan Please provide a stackblitz if the issue is still there

Answer (score 1):

It seems your API response is returning a customer object which has emails, name and surname field.

Modify your interfaces like this:

```
    export interface Customer {
       customer : CustomerDetails;
    }

   export interface CustomerDetails{
        name: string;
        surname: string;
        emails: Array<Emails>;
   }

    export interface Emails {
        address: string;
    }
```

Comment: It gave me TS2339: Property 'emails' does not exist on type 'Customer'.

Comment: Can you please your post where you are using it?

Comment: I solved it by using:
export interface CustomerContainer {
    customer: Customer;
    rCode: number;
}

export interface Customer {
    name: string;
    surname: string;
    emails:Array<Emails>;
}

export interface Emails {
    address: string;
    id:number;
    notes:string;
    wsDataValueCode:string;
}